# How to resolve 'runtime memory ordering' in AtomicPointer of leveldb?

Tags: assembly, atomic, leveldb

```
// Gcc on x86
inline void MemoryBarrier() {
  // See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2003-04/msg01180.html for a discussion on
  // this idiom. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering.
  __asm__ __volatile__("" : : : "memory");
}
```

‘**asm** **volatile**("" : : : "memory")’ can only resolve compile-time memory ordering, I cann't understand how to resolve runtime memory ordering.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965076/gcc-memory-barrier-sync-synchronize-vs-asm-volatile-memory)

Comment: What makes you think you have a problem with runtime memory ordering?  Gcc has builtins for hw fencing (`__builtin_ia32_mfence` et al), but you shouldn't use them unless you actually need them.