# How does 64bit integer type guarantee atomicity on 32bit operation system?

Tags: c++, operating-system, window, computer-science, atomic

As I know, 64bit integer work differently by operation system.
I could find out that is true in assembly instructions. Below like this.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t sharedValue = 0;
    sharedValue = 0x100000002;    
}
```

[32bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAfGu.png)
[64bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFMma.png)

So I thought a 32bit operation system couldn't guarantee the atomicity of the 64bit integer because the operation consists of multiple instructions. But 64bit operation system can.

So I checked the 64-bit integer. To see how atomicity is guaranteed depending on the operating system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    atomic<uint64_t> num;
    cout << boolalpha << num.is_lock_free() << endl;
}
```

[32bit atomicity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7HAC.png)
[64bit atomicity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ldK.png)

As I know, 'lock_is_free = true' means this type can be processed atomically in the CPU.

if i understood correctly, why dose a 64bit integer on 32bit os return 'true' by lock_is_free().

Assembly codes are multiple, but some operations can be processed atomicity on CPU??

Please, Answer my problem.

Comment: I just tried with `gcc` and checked the disassembly: `gcc` uses the FPU registers to store a `atomic<uint64_t>`. The FPU registers allow atomic 64-bit integer operations.

Comment: Most architectures provide some mechanism for an  atomic double-wide compare and swap, which on a 32-bit system would let you compare and swap a 64-bit object.  With a CAS loop, that lets you do any kind of atomic read-modify-write on a 64-bit object in a lock-free fashion; in particular you can do a store by just disregarding the old value.  It will be at least an order of magnitude slower than an ordinary store instruction, but it's still lock-free.  64-bit systems likewise use this technique to provide lock-free 128-bit types.

Comment: So on x86-32, if FPU or SSE loads and stores weren't atomic, you'd still be able to use [`cmpxchg8b`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg8b:cmpxchg16b) to get the same effect (more slowly).

Answer (score 0):

This stack overflow answer shows how it's done an x86.  Presumably other architectures have similar instructions.

[How to guarantee 64-bit writes are atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78277/how-to-guarantee-64-bit-writes-are-atomic)